# Why is my CSS Bootstrap not working in Codesandbox?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I used some Bootstrap in the code editor at Codesandbox, but it's not working so my images look messy and oversized. How can I manage to use Bootstrap inside my Codesandbox? If anybody knows please help me! Thank you so much!

This is my Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-30bgi?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2):

**Just add the following Bootstrap CDN link into your public/index.html file's head tag**

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: can you tell me where do you put it in index.js? cause i put it at the top and it's not working ...

Comment: @sugasunshie just add the bootstrap CDN link into index.html file's head tag (inside public directory) not into index.js. I have already mentioned all the steps in answer window please read carefully.

Comment: After adding it I have tested your app on Codesandbox it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**After a long year, it is still not working**.

***but it works when you simply add your bootstrap through CDN links***

> just add any one of these in your root (index.html)

```
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or----->

```
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also resolved by adding `bootstrap` as a dependency in codesandbox *and* `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`to `App.js` or `src/index.js` (due to the cascading nature of CSS, make sure it is imported after any other stylesheets).

In the instance when `react-bootstrap` is used in codesandbox, it is necessary to have `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` as dependencies, with the stylesheet imported as above.

The react-bootstrap docs have a substantiating explanation for this [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets).